# JanusGraph: access Amazon Managed Cassandra from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cql, janusgraph, amazon-keyspaces

I'm trying to set up JanusGraph to access Amazon MCS. The infrastructure is all there to allow access, but I'm facing difficulties at the config step.

This is the config I'm setting for `janusgraph-cql.properties`:

```
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=cassandra.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
storage.port=9142
storage.username=${CASSANDRA_USERNAME}
storage.password=${CASSANDRA_PASSWORD}
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.location=${CASSANDRA_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.password=${CASSANDRA_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}
storage.cql.ssl.enabled=true
```

Amazon MCS exposes port 9142, instead of 9402.

When I start `gremlin-server.sh`, I can see the following outputs:

```
2897 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.116.141:9042 added
2898 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.117.140:9042 added
2898 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.117.134:9042 added
2898 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.116.137:9042 added
2898 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.116.182:9042 added
2899 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host cassandra.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/13.251.117.0:9142 added
2899 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.116.84:9042 added
2899 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.117.219:9042 added
2899 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.116.144:9042 added
2899 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /13.251.116.1:9042 added
```

Even though I've set the port to 9142, new Cassandra hosts with port 9042 are still being added, making the process fail (since 9042 is not available). Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hm. Those machines with port 9042 will likely be reported to you by the machine you're initially connecting with. It will tell you everything it knows so far about the topology. Do you have any more specific error messages that indicate a problem with the 9042 machines?

Comment: It turned out it was an error with AWS Managed Cassandra not supporting JanusGraph. I can't remember the exact details though :)